Let $f$ be a positive, measurable function on $(0,1)$. What are conditions on $f$ such that $f^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ almost everywhere?
Let $f$ be a positive, measurable function on $(0,1)$. What are conditions on $f$ such that $f^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ almost everywhere?
$\textbf{Thoughts.}$ If the function $f$ is bounded then I think it will always converge to $1$. However, I also believe that functions like $f(x)=1/x$ also works, so I do not think boundedness is not a necessary condition.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

We are talking pointwise convergence, so you really don't need special conditions, especially that $f > 0$. Isn't this equivalent to ${f = \infty}$ having measure $0$?

@User Thank you, that makes sense. I think we only need finite almost everywhere rather than boundedness.
